# Cannot parse a CSV file - "CSV::MalformedCSVError: Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, smartercsv

I am trying to parse uploaded CSV files. Here's the full error message:

```
[Worker(host:PC.local pid:69594)] Job ImportJob (id=4) FAILED (3 prior attempts) with CSV::MalformedCSVError: Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n (line 1).
```

And the CSV files looks like this:

```
A1;A2;A3;A4;A5
B1;B2;B3;B4;B5
C1;C2;C3;C4;C5
```

And this is how I loop through the data in the CSV file:

```
data = SmarterCSV.process(
  file,
  {
    :col_sep => ';',
    :chunk_size => 100,
    :remove_empty_values => false,
    :remove_empty_hashes => false
  }
) do |d|
```

What's the problem here? I've tried to put the headline to the file, even tried to remove it (the version posted above), but in both cases I get the same error. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: What machine are you working on (windows? mac?) was the file created on that machine?

Comment: Mac. I created the CSV file from an XLS file (that was created on Windows probably).

Comment: I have seen something similar with a CSV file that was exported out of MS Excel.  To fix it I essentially just did a `gsub` to swap out any carriage returns.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the CSV file was created on Windows, it's not surprising that the line endings are "\r\n".  Try explicitly making that your row separator:

```
:row_sep => "\r"
```

Putting it all together:

```
data = SmarterCSV.process(file, 
  :col_sep => ';', 
  :row_sep => "\r", 
  :chunk_size => 100, 
  :remove_empty_values => false, 
  :remove_empty_hashes => false) do |d|
```

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same error (even restart of the app didn't help).

Comment: What about making the row_sep `\r\n`?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this exact problem but with the built-in CSV module.

I solved it by using the IO read mode as text: 'rt', not 'r':

```
require 'csv'

CSV.open(file_name, 'rt').each do |row|
  # blah, blah
end
```